# NAudio pitch shifting

Tags: .net, audio, signal-processing, naudio, pitch-shifting

I am using the NAudio DLL and I am looking for example code for pitch shifting sound.

Comment: Why are we voting to close this? It's not the best phrased question, but a very common FAQ for audio DSP in .NET

Comment: @MarkHeath, is NAudio capable of changing by Hz? I have an old recording that is a bit of pitch (not a complete semitone), and I want to fix it so I can add music to it. Is this doable with NAudio? Any sample usage?

Answer (score 8):

There is an example of using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) for pitch shifting in the open source [Skype Voice Changer](https://github.com/markheath/skypevoicechanger) project. See my article on [Coding4Fun](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Skype-Voice-Changer) for more information on the project. The pitch shifter code itself is found in the [SuperPitch](https://github.com/markheath/skypevoicechanger/blob/master/SkypeVoiceChanger/Effects/SuperPitch.cs) class.

Comment: The link to the `SuperPitch` class is no longer available.

Comment: seems there is currently a problem with the codeplex site. hopefully the outage is temporary